# ¿A qué se debe la vulnerabilidad TrustManager cuando intento públicar una app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

Hola comunidad espero que me puedan ayudar con este detalle, pasa que quiero publicar una aplicación en Google Play (la esto intentando publicar en el canal de producción), pero me sale el siguiente mensaje

[image: Imagen de respuesta de Google Play Console]

Tenia implementado esta función :

```
@SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
public void handleSSLHandshake() {
    try {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new NullHostNameVerifier());
        SSLContext mSslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return new X509Certificate[] {}; }
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
        }};
        mSslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(mSslContext.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class NullHostNameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Actualmente para la versión que envíe a revisión la tengo comentado por que en unos artículos leí que es muy insegura esta forma (por ello la comente, no la tengo eliminado del código solo esta comentado), mande una nueva versión con otras sugerencias que me fui encontrando en la búsqueda como son :

En mi carpeta XML (dos archivos):

Archivo 1.- network_security_config.xml

[image: Archivo 1]

Archivo 2.- provider_paths.xml

[image: Archivo 2]

Y en mi AndroidManifest.xml tengo lo siguiente para usarlos, como atributo de mi etiqueta `<application _justo_aqui_ ></application>`
[image: Atributo]

y dentro de esta etiqueta `<application> _justo_aqui_ </application>`:

[image: Elemento]

Actualmente mi código de ejecución esta de la siguiente forma :

```
        connection.handleSSLHandshake();
        String url = "URL_con_HTTPS";
        AList = new ArrayList<>();
        sendAndRequestResponse(url, view);
```

Si ven esta función en realidad es una función vacía, no tengo nada:

```
connection.handleSSLHandshake();
```

El código de este es el siguiente :

```
public void handleSSLHandshake() {
}
```

Que como mencionaba en la parte de arriba, tengo comentado las acciones de esa función y que en realidad esta de la siguiente forma (no sé si es esto lo que hace que la rechacen, especulando claro).

[image: código implementado]

¿Por qué la tengo así?, bueno digamos que estaba haciendo una prueba y como esa función estaba en varios archivos la puse de esa manera, la iba a remover pero se me paso (por eso comentaba que no sabía si era eso que afectaba).

--> **Actualización**

Cargue la app nuevamente implementando esta función, pero de igual forma me la rechazaron (por el mismo problema TrustManager)

```
@SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
public static void handleSSLHandshake() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509ExtendedTrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) throws CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) throws CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) throws CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) throws CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {

            }

            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
            }
        }};

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((arg0, arg1) -> true);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
```

No se si estoy haciendo algo mal con respecto a esta situación, les agradecería su ayuda, comento también que este es mi Gradle (en caso de que sea de relevancia)

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

// Splash Gif
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.19'

// Navigation Bar
// noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

// Volley internet
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

// Para cargar de imagen online
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

// Firebase
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.0.2'

// Maps
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'

// Escaner QR
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.2.0'

// SDK de facebook
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

// OneSignal
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'

// Scale image
implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.10.0'
```

y el SDK es `targetSdkVersion 29`

-----> **Actualización (publicada)**

Ya he logrado publicar la app, en caso de que alguien más tenga un problema similar, para llegar a la solución simplemente actualize los `implementation` que tengo en el Gradle a las más actuales

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

// Splash Gif
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.19'

// Navigation Bar
// noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

// Volley internet
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'

// Para cargar de imagen online
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

// Firebase
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.3'

// Maps
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'

// Escaner QR
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.2.0'

// SDK de facebook
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.42.0'

// OneSignal
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.16.0'

// Scale image
implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.10.0'
```

De esta forma quedo mi Gradle, solo actualize y cargue de nuevo y me la aprobaron casi enseguida.

Les dejo lo que a mi me funciono.

Saludos amigos

Answer (score 3):

Como lo comentas, una solución es dejar de usar esta implementación, eliminando el método `HandleSSLShake` que usa la clase `X509TrustManager`, de esta forma ya no tendrás la alerta al subir tu app a Google Play.

```
/* 
@SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
public void handleSSLHandshake() {
    try {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new NullHostNameVerifier());
        SSLContext mSslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return new X509Certificate[] {}; }
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
        }};
        mSslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(mSslContext.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class NullHostNameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
}*/
```

De hecho si en verdad la necesitas deberías de usar `X509ExtendedTrustManager` en lugar de `X509TrustManager`.

---

Actualización:

**Debes revisar en tu aplicación todos los llamados al método `handleSSLHandshake()` y eliminarlos así como los imports que usa este método**, ejemplo:

```
/*import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;*/
...
...
    /*if(Global.trustAllHttpsHosts && url.getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase("https"))
                    handleSSLHandshake();*/
```

Comment: Ok, probaré las dos formas, pasa que ya había cargado la app pero con esta función comentada, la probaré cargando de nuevo pero eliminando todo el registro de esta función y en dado caso que me la rechacen de nuevo probaré implementando X509ExtendedTrustManager, muchas gracias @Jorgesys

Comment: Claro, de hecho me acordaste que tenìa comentado ese mètodo precisamente porque lo estaba usando y se tenìa la misma alerta en Google Play, ya lo eliminè ;-)

Comment: Hola! de nuevo amigo, no funciono ninguna de las dos opciones :c, te pongo en contexto, actuaizaré la ficha

Comment: @J.Aban Debe funcionar, asegura eliminar todos los llamados, me parece que te falta eliminar los imports, es importante revisa mi actualización, saludos.

Comment: De hecho así lo tengo, elimine todo, no deje ni imports, ni nada que tenga que ver con el TrustManager, por ello se me hace raro, lo deje tal cual comentaste, pero ahora dare una revisada al proyecto entero para estar al 100% seguro. @Jorgesys